# KivyMD | List Item print its "text" on_press

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How can I code a OneLineListItem in KivyMD to print its "text" on a console?
I came up with something like this:

```
[...]
item = OneLineListItem(text="DEMO", on_press= lambda x: ??????? )
list.add_widget(item)
[...]
```

I would like to have the word "DEMO" printed on the console after pressing on Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
item = OneLineListItem(text="DEMO", on_press=lambda x: print(x.text))
```

Comment: It is not working with multiple dynamicly created items. It always prints the last one text

Comment: Updated the answer. It should be ```print(x.text)``` and this will work for dynamically created items as well.